# Maximal normal subgroups and quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, algebraic-groups

I am trying to understand quotient groups and their implications, I came across a theorem: if G is a group, and M is a maximal normal subgroup of G,then G/M is simple. The issue is assuming by contradiction that G/M is not simple, there exists a proper normal subgroup A/M of G/M. I understand that implies A contains M which is a contradiction since M is maximal.
The issue I have is: why does A must contain M? given A/M is normal in G/M.

Comment: If $G$ is a group, and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, **every** subgroup of $G/N$ is of the form $H/N$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ *that contains $N$* (so that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ and we can take the quotient).

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)

Answer (score 0):

> there exists a proper normal subgroup A/M of G/M

This presupposes that $M$ is a subgroup of $A$. I think you are referring to the following argument. If $G/M$ is not simple, then there exists a proper normal subgroup $A'$ of $G/M$.

Let $\phi$ be the canonical homomorphism from $G$ to $G/M$. Let $A=\phi^{-1}(A')$. Now, it can be shown that $A$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$ containing $M$. The fact that $A$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$ follows without much difficulty from the definition of the homomorphism $\phi$. Now, $A$ contains $M$ because it can be easily shown that $M$ is contained in $\phi^{-1}(e)$ where $e$ is the identity element in $G/M$.